# Очень не/неинтересная тема

Tags: орфография, частица-не, прилагательные

Как, скажите, пожалуйста, правильно? Я думаю, что 2-й вариант правильный.

1. Это была очень ненеинтересная тема.
2. Это была очень не неинтересная тема.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Не неинтересный* — такая конструкция похожа на двойное отрицание, которое придает высказыванию смысл утверждения, а не отрицания (= интересный).
Пишется она раздельно и встречается нечасто (наречие "очень" здесь, мне кажется, не подходит; можно использовать другие: никоим образом, вовсе, совсем, отнюдь).

*То, что все знают — тривиальности — тоже **не неинтересны*** (А. А. Сарибан. Дневник).

*...not by any means unpalatable (никоим образом **не невкусный** = вовсе не противен на вкус)* (Английский с Оскаром Уайльдом) [Илья Франк]

Анатолий Трушкин. Невезучий:

> Я говорю:
> — Галя, я **не невезучий**.
> Она:
> — А кто тогда? Ты хоть раз прошел по улице, чтобы на тебя птицы не нагадили?

*Закон Бога о крови, конечно, не новый и **не неясный*** (из журнала).

Comment: **Римма**, предложите Леопольду заменить «очень» на «совсем». Или «вовсе».

Comment: Да, пожалуй. Спасибо. Хотя в примерах эти наречия уже есть. P. S. А вы посмотрели объяснения о "в леску́" (про местный падеж)?

Comment: То есть, даже несмотря на то что есть наречие-утверждение *очень*, надо писать раздельно?

Answer (score 1):

Возможны два варианта записи **с указанным смыслом:**

Усиление **утверждения**: *Это была **очень** неинтересная тема.*

Усиление **отрицания**: *Это была **отнюдь не** интересная тема.*

**Пояснение**

1. Наречие меры и степени ***очень*** усиливает только утвердительный смысл. Усиление отрицания возможно с помощью сочетания "***отнюдь не"*** по отношению к прилагательному "интересный".
2. Сочетание "***не неинтересный***" можно встретить в определенном **контексте**, например в диалоге, когда слово ***неинтересный*** с приставкой НЕ уже использовано собеседником.

Это **просто отрицание** уже сказанного, но **двойного отрицания** с утвердительным смыслом я здесь не вижу. Например:

*— Это **неинтересная** тема!  — Тема **не неинтересная** сама по себе, просто надо уметь интересно рассказать об этом.*

**Более частотный** вариант с тем же смыслом: *Тема **не то чтобы неинтересная** сама по себе, просто надо уметь интересно рассказать об этом.*

**Приложение к ответу (словарь, правило)**

**НЕИНТЕРЕСНЫЙ.** 1. Не возбуждающий интереса; скучный. Н. рассказ, урок. Спектакль получился неинтересным. // Не вызывающий интереса из-за умственной или духовной ограниченности. Н. человек. Н-ые знакомые. Она очень неинтересна как собеседник. 2. Разг. Некрасивый, непривлекательный. Н-ое лицо. Н-ая внешность. Н-ая расцветка ткани.

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=77#pp77) об усилительных словах**

**Пункт 6.** Если в качестве пояснительного слова выступает **наречие меры и степени** (весьма, крайне, **очень**, почти или наречное выражение в высшей степени и т. п.), то частица не с прилагательным **всегда пишется слитно:** весьма некрасивый поступок; крайне неуместный выпад; очень неудачное выступление; почти незнакомый текст; в высшей степени неразборчивый почерк.

**Пункт 8(2).** При наличии в качестве пояснительных слов **далеко, вовсе, отнюдь или** отрицательных местоимений и наречий (начинающихся с ни): далеко не простое решение; вовсе не бесплодные поиски; отнюдь не новый сюжет; никому не известный адрес; ни в чём не повинные люди; нисколько не понятное выражение; ничуть не вредный напиток; никому не ведомыми путями (ср.: неведомыми мне путями).

**Пункт 7.** При использовании в качестве пояснительного слова наречия ***совсем*** возможно как слитное, так и раздельное написание частицы не с прилагательными, что связано с разными значениями, в которых употребляется слово ***совсем***. Ср.: совсем ненужная встреча (‘совершенно ненужная, лишняя’) — совсем не случайная встреча (‘отнюдь не случайная’). В некоторых случаях возможны два толкования и, как следствие, допустимы два написания: совсем небольшие достижения (‘маленькие, скромные’) — совсем не большие достижения (‘отнюдь не большие’).